# Flutter: Positioned SizedBox overlay in Stack to show loading seems hacky

Tags: flutter

I have an app where users can cause a card to go into a loading state (say there's a toggle switch on the card). I want the card to have a transparent grey overlay while it's loading with a circular loading indicator while it's calling the server. This all works fine with the code below.

However in order for the overlay to cover the whole card (and be sure it covers all device sizes) I had to put the width as an arbitrary high number since `double.infinity` caused an exception. Is there a better way to do what I've done?

```
Card(
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Title'),
        subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xff3d6be1)))
        )
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: isLoading ? 0.5 : 0.0,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            width: 100000, // <---- this seems hacky
            child: const DecoratedBox(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey
              ),
            )
          )
        )
      ),

    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: try to use Positioned.fill()

Comment: Oh yeah, that worked. Cheers! If you add it as an answer I'll close the question @Eugene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `Positioned.fill`

it creates a Positioned object with [left], [top], [right], and [bottom] set to 0.0 unless a value for them is passed

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Opacity(
        //
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To better control the width you can use Media Query:

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; <-- Here

Card(
    child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
                title: Text('Title'),
                subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
                ),
            Center(
                child: Opacity(
                    opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xff3d6be1)))
                )
            ),
            Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Opacity(
                    opacity: isLoading ? 0.5 : 0.0,
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                        width: width,      <-- And here use it
                        child: const DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey
                        ),
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ]
    )
)
```

And so you are using the exact width of the device.

Comment: I used `Positioned.fill()` suggested from the comment on the question which seems to be the cleanest way.